# Anonymous ftp connection with tFTPConnection

Tags: java, talend

Is there a way using the tFTPconnection (or another talend component) to do an anonymous connection to FTP.

I'm looking for the equivalent of this command :

`> ftp -A [-s filename] [host]`

Comment: In the component tFTPconnexion the default user value is "annonymous" maybe you can try to let this value and make a test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component tFTPconnexion the default user value is "annonymous" you can try to let this value.